# Discrepancy in solutions of differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hyperbolic-functions

The differential equation at hand is this :

$$ \frac{\text{d}\psi}{\text{d}x}+2\tanh(x)\,\psi\left(x\right)=0\ $$
And what I have tried is this :
$$ 
\int_{}^{} \frac{\text{d}\psi}{\psi}=-2\int_{}^{} \tanh(x)\,dx$$
and
$$ \ln\psi \left(x\right)=-2\cosh^{-2}\left(x\right)+C\  $$

And the solution of this elementary problem comes out to be :
$$ \psi\left(x\right)=Ae^{-2\cosh^{-2}\left(x\right)}$$
But clearly, 
$$ \psi\left(x\right)\ = \cosh^{-2}\left(x\right)\ $$
is a solution. But why can't I find it through integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, we have that
$$\int\tanh(x) dx=\int\frac{d(\cosh(x))}{\cosh(x)}=\ln(\cosh(x))+c$$
and
$$D(\tanh(x))=\frac{1}{\cosh^2(x)}.$$
So you confused the derivative with the integral...

Comment: Oh! Thanks, I didn't thought about that.

Comment: @JalajChaturvedi Well done. BTW, if you are new here, please take a few minutes for a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour